# Add icon in selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I want search icon at the extreme left like image shown below in selectize. Search icon of fontawesome is `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>` OR we can use Glyphicons  of bootstrap.

content: "\e003"; font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";

I couldn't find method to add icon when multiple selection is enabled.

[image: search]

**HTML**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    
    <select multiple class="form-control select-key" id="sel2" name="key-list[]">
      <option>SBI Cap</option>
      <option>PGIM MidCap</option>
      <option>Axis SmallCap</option>
      <option>Kotak Technology</option>
      <option>SBI Technology</option>
    </select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
   $("#sel2").selectize({
    onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
        if (!this.lastQuery.length) {
        this.close(); 
        this.settings.openOnFocus = false;
      }
   },   
   onItemAdd: function() {
    this.close();
   },
   onType : function (str) {
        if (str === "") {
            this.close();
        }
   }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the icon in `before` css psudo class.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#sel2").selectize({
        onDropdownOpen: function($dropdown) {
            if (!this.lastQuery.length) {
                this.close();
                this.settings.openOnFocus = false;
            }
        },
        onItemAdd: function() {
            this.close();
        },
        onType: function(str) {
            if (str === "") {
                this.close();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
 .selectize-input.items.not-full.has-options:before {
 content:"\f002";
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 line-height: 2;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0 4px;
 font-weight:900;
 }
  .selectize-input.items.not-full.has-options {
 padding-left: 24px;
 }
 
   .selectize-input.items.not-full.has-options .item:first-child {
 margin-left: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br>
<select multiple class="form-control select-key" id="sel2" name="key-list[]">
    <option>SBI Cap</option>
    <option>PGIM MidCap</option>
    <option>Axis SmallCap</option>
    <option>Kotak Technology</option>
    <option>SBI Technology</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. When user enters value, search icon appears at the left. Can we freeze it? OR if we can have static icon at the extreme left instead of right (sorry for changing the position after asking initially)

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari I updated the code. Try again.